# Know when a FireBase Notification has been clicked

Tags: android, firebase

Is there a way to know that a user has clicked on a notification when the application is in the foreground?

I need to send analytics for when users click on the notification and I need to know when they have clicked it.

I can't put the analytics in the destination activity as I have other analytics that are sent when the user gets to that screen. I need to know that a user has specifically clicked on the notification to open the destination activity.

For example is there a callback for when a user clicks on the notification?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you should `.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)` in NotificationCompat.Builder
and put into this intent variable, then, on app start, you should check if this variable exists in intent of destination activity and if it is true, send analytics
if it is what you want, i can give code sample

Comment: This is not ideal as i will have to have the analytics placed in each destination activity. I mean this can work but we are going to be adding other screens that will be the destination and it would mean having to implement that on all the destination screens

Comment: @x10sion You could create a base class for destination screens.

Comment: Cant u just make AnalyticsHelper and in destination activity only call AnalyticsHelper.getInstance().trackPushOpen() ? And then u wont implement it in each activity, just 1 call. No?